# Android Studio, error after deleting a module

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I deleted local version of module but when I compile it gradle outputs this error :

```
Failed to complete gradle execution
Already disposed: Module: 'twoWayView'
```

[image]

Comment: Try restarting AS. If that doesn't work, reimport the project from Gradle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off check if the module is gone gone from *all* of your build.gradle files.

Next, if restarting Android Studio doesn't fix things for you, try running a `./gradlew clean build`.

If that doesn't work, do this:

[image]